# Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long

Tags: php

Getting the following error:

> Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /home/15063/brooks/www.brooks-shopping.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/themes/sandbox/functions.php
>   on line 546

Which points to the line:

```
$day = date("l, F jS", get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date_value', true));
```

Can someone suggest, what changes are required to the above line to resolve this please?

Comment: And what does ` get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date_value', true)` return? should be a time() value (integer)

Comment: `var_dump(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date_value', true));` and see what it returns.

Comment: "long" is a numeric type, as it says you're giving it a string instead.

Comment: @PLB var_dump of a function call? a yep never mind it works, i thought this function took mandatorily a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date expects parameter 2 to be a long. i.e. it expects a number to be returned.

You return a string (assuming) with `get_post_meta`
You need to convert it to a time first before you can return it (a date long)

Instead try

```
$day = date("l, F jS", strtotime(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date_value', true)));
```

The `strtotime` function return an `int` as shown [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `get_post_meta` returns the time in string, try this and see if it works

```
$day = date("l, F jS", strtotime(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date_value', true)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to int first like this:

```
$day = date("l, F jS", (int) get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date_value', true));
```

Comment: Hmm, what if `get_post_meta` returns date in string format (e.g. `'2012-14-12').

Comment: @PLB In that case this won't work but do you know if `get_post_meta` is returning date in string format (e.g. `'2012-14-12') ?

Comment: in that case, `strtotime` will work. Anyway, it seems question is too localized and missing some important information.

Comment: @PLB: I agree but if `get_post_meta` is returning date like `seconds since Epoch` then `strtotime` won't work.